# in Qt how to know which component (placed on a widget or form ) is currently focused?

Tags: qt

I am doing work on Qt. i am not using android. It's just a desktop application running on windows/linux.how to know which component (placed on a widget or form )  is currently focused ?

i have onscreen keyboard which appears when a QLineEdit,QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit get focused and hide when these lost focus.But when i switch focuse from one TextEdit(or lineEdit,PlainTextEdit) to Another TextEdit(or lineEdit,PlainTextEdit) my keyboard hide and again show.I just want to stop this

Comment: What do you mean focused? Like a textEdit will have the user's keyboard focused, but other widgets such as a QGraphicsView or a Button how do you determine focus?

Comment: i have onscreen keyboard which appears when a QLineEdit,QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit get focused and hide when these lost focus.But when i switch focuse from one TextEdit(or lineEdit,PlainTextEdit) to Another TextEdit(or lineEdit,PlainTextEdit) my keyboard hide and again show.I just want to stop this

Comment: `QApplication` has a [focusChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#focusChanged) signal, if that's what you're looking for. Or you can use it's [focusWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#focusWidget) function to see what widget currently has focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the keyboard from flickering when the widget it's coming from and the one it's going to are similar then you could perhaps implement a timer. I imagine you have the lost focus signals going to your code that is hiding the keyboard. Instead of really hiding it, you can start a timer like

```
QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SLOT(really_close_keyb()));
```

Within that really_close_keyb() slot you could implement code to check if the widget that currently has focus should have a keyboard or not, and if it should then you don't hide it.

With this your keyboard will be up for 1/2 sec after the user focuses out of a line edit, giving enough time to focus on another one without losing the keyboard. Adjust the timing to suit.